# MPVolumeView not showing in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6.3

This code works fine on a physical iPhone 6, but on iOS simulator the MPVolumeView doesn't show.

```
- (void)setUpVolumeView
{    
    CGRect sliderRect = CGRectMake(20, 400, 300, 20);
    self.myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:sliderRect];
    [self.view addSubview: self.myVolumeView];
}
```

`self` is in this case a ViewController.

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MPVolumeView has, as far back my memory goes, never worked in the simulator. It's always either shown nothing or displayed "No volume available" in white text.

Comment: Changed the background to grey to see which it was. No text, no volume view. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because it has to reflect the system value which is not controllable through the simulator (i.e no volume hardware buttons as there are on the actual device).